# pinging mysql using mysql alchemy and python

Tags: python, mysql

how do i ping mysql using mysql alchemy and python?

Comment: I think you need to explain a little better what you want to do.  By 'ping', do you mean 'connect to'?  By 'mysql alchemy' do you mean 'SQLAlchemy'?

Answer (score 2):

Use mysqlshow to see if MySQL is running as expected.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlshow.html

Assure that SQLAlchemy has supprt for MySQL.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/dbengine.html#supported-dbapis

Use a simple query through SQLAlchemy.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html